# Как перенаправить клиент на другую страницу через websockets?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, asyncio

Есть простой пример использования `websockets` в качестве сервера на python3. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу при вернополученном запросе к серверу

Python:

```
import websockets, asyncio, json

async def hello(websocket, path): # На стороне сервера websocket выполняет 
    # сопрограмму обработчика hello один раз для каждого соединения
    ask = await websocket.recv() # Получение данных с клиента
    ask = json.loads(ask)
    print(ask)

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 5666) # Старт сервака
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server) # Асинхронный запуск до тех пор, пока сервак не заработает
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

HTML/JS:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var mark = document.getElementById("mark").value;
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5666/")
    ws.onopen = function () {
        let data = {
            name: name,
            mark: mark
        };
        let json = JSON.stringify(data);
        ws.send(json);
    };
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <input placeholder="ФИО" type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <input placeholder="Результат" type="text" name="mark" id="mark">
        <button type="submit" id="btn">Отправить</button>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: только яваскриптом